# How to use a WebAPI Catch all but allow root and help URIs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net WebApi REST service where I would like to format my own message for a 404 (ie route not found). I am using attribute routing.

All of my controller routes are nested under `v1/`. Also, for just the root url, I display a pain html page (ie I provide a default.htm file), an also under the /help I show some help (via mvc help pages). So, I don't want the 'catch all' route to intercept these urls.

I found [this post](http://www.matrichard.com/post/webapi-catch-all-route-or-having-a-default-route-when-a-route-is-not-found), which seemed to work, even in conjunction with the attribute routing,  except it also does trap my root page.

I tried the following

```
httpConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ResourceNotFound",
        routeTemplate: "{uri}/{*v1}",
        defaults: new { controller = "ResourceNotFound", uri = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

ie added the `{*v1}`, however this does not work either. I get the following (my catch all controller is named `ResourceNotFoundController`)

```
 <Error>
    <Message>
      No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/myapi/'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
       No action was found on the controller 'ResourceNotFound' that matches the request.
    </MessageDetail>
 </Error>
```

I have tried various variations of `routeTemplate` patterns, but can't get it to work where it allows the root page through.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Add a route for the root page before so it is not caught by the catch-all

Comment: Show currently configured routes.